# Power BI bar chart to count column totals

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a dataset of products and the categories they belong to. Each product can belong to 1 or more categories (C1, C2, etc).

[image]

My goal is to generate a bar chart in Power BI to count how many products belong to each category. Something like this:

[image]

This is very easy to do in Excel but I just couldn't figure out how to do that in PowerBI... The closest I got was using a clustered column chart. But everything was crammed in the center since I only have one "cluster".

[image]

I feel I'm missing something very basic but can't figure out what. Any help is appreciated!

Note: I cannot modify the dataset in any way. I can create new dataset if needed but prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot your C1....C5 columns.
Then in your chart use your values as "values" and your created pivot column for  axis.
Now you will see that the c1 c2 .... will be on the x axis.
You can show the counts by changing the calculation of you values to count.

Hope this helps